# Nonexpansive mapping

Tags: functional-analysis

Taking $=_0$
and $=\{=\{_\}\in _0:0≤_≤1\}$

and defining $T\colon B\to B$
by
$(_1,_2,⋯)=(1,_1,_2,⋯)$.Then
B is non-empty, closed, bounded and convex. Also,
$T$ maps $B$ into $$, is nonexpansive. I am trying to find sequence in $B$ satisfies $Tx_n -x_n$ converges to zero (I mean approximate sequence). But I can not find it.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $n$ and let
$$x^{(n)}_k=\begin{cases} 1-{k\over n}& 1\le k\le n-1\\
0 & k\ge n
\end{cases}$$ Then $x^{(n)}\in c_0$ and
$$(Tx^{(n)}-x^{(n)})_k=\begin{cases}{1\over n} & 1\le k\le n\\ 0 & k\ge n+1
\end{cases}$$
Hence $$\|Tx^{(n)}-x^{(n)}\|_\infty ={1\over n}  \underset{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$$

Another example: for $0<r<1$ let $x^{(r)}=\{r^n\}_{n=1}^\infty.$ Then $$\|Tx^{(r)}-x^{(r)}\|_\infty =1-r\underset{r\to 1^-}{\longrightarrow} 0$$

Comment: Thank you dear, the norm in the last line is it equal 1 because the supermum of sequence 1/n equal 1, can you give me more clearfications

Comment: The norm in the last line is equal $1/n.$ When $n$ tends to infinity the limit is $0.$